# I am getting an "error: int cannot be dereferenced" for my program designed to sequentially, iteratively, and recursively search a .txt file

Tags: java

In the main method, I've tried .equals() and .compareTo() and they both give me the same error at lines 88, 94, and 100. When I use ==, it compiles, but gives me the following when it runs:

```
Type the word you're searching for. Or type -1 to stop: curse
sequentialSearch()      : curse is not found (comparison=13040).
iterative binarySearch(): curse is not found (comparison=13).
recursive binarySearch(): curse is not found (comparison=13).
Type the word you're searching for. Or type -1 to stop:
```

I know the word "curse" is in the text file I'm searching.

This is the code I have so far.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Search extends Object {
public static final String TO_STOP = "-1";
public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;

public static int count1;
public static int count2;
public static int count3;

public Search()
{
    count1 = 0;
    count2 = 0;
    count3 = 0;
}

public static int sequentialSearch(ArrayList<String> array, String value)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = array.size() - 1;
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++){
        count1++;
        if (array.get(i) == value)
            return i;
    }
    return NOT_FOUND;
}

public static int binarySearch(ArrayList<String> array, String value)
{
    int low = 0;
            int high = array.size() - 1;
            while (low <= high) {
                int mid = (low + high)/2;
                if (array.get(mid) != value){
                    count2++;
                    high = mid - 1;
                } else if (array.get(mid) != value){
                    count2++;
                    low = mid + 1;
                } else
                    return mid;
            }
    return NOT_FOUND;
}

public static int binarySearch(ArrayList<String> array, int low, int high, String value)
{
    if (low > high)
                return NOT_FOUND;
            int mid = (low + high)/2;
            if (array.get(mid) != value){
                count3++;
                return binarySearch(array, low, mid-1, value);
            } else if (array.get(mid) != value){
                count3++;
                return binarySearch(array, mid+1, high, value);
            } else
        return mid;
}

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    File fn = new File("sortedWords.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fn);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean wantsToContinue = true;

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String ln = sc.nextLine();
        array.add(ln);
        }

        do {
            System.out.print("Type the word you're searching for. Or type " + TO_STOP + " to stop: ");
            String word2search = keyboard.nextLine();

            if(word2search.equals(TO_STOP)){
                wantsToContinue = false;
            }
            else {
                int index;
                index = sequentialSearch(array, word2search);
                if (index.compareTo(NOT_FOUND))
                    System.out.println("sequentialSearch()      : " + word2search + " is not found (comparison=" + count1 + ").");
                else
                    System.out.println("sequentialSearch()      : " + word2search + " is found in [" + index + "] (comparison=" + count1 + ").");

                index = binarySearch(array, word2search);
                if (index.compareTo(NOT_FOUND))
                    System.out.println("iterative binarySearch(): " + word2search + " is not found (comparison=" + count2 + ").");
                else
                    System.out.println("iterative binarySearch(): " + word2search + " is found in [" + index + "] (comparison=" + count2 + ").");

                index = binarySearch(array, 0, array.size()-1, word2search);
                if (index.compareTo(NOT_FOUND))
                    System.out.println("recursive binarySearch(): " + word2search + " is not found (comparison=" + count3 + ").");
                else
                    System.out.println("recursive binarySearch(): " + word2search + " is found in [" + index + "] (comparison=" + count3 + ").");
                        }
    } while (wantsToContinue);
}
```

}

Comment: No need to extend the Object class.It is extended automatically.

Comment: Also, check your if statements. It's full of (if something1) ... else if (something1). That is definitely not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use compareTo() or equals on int since int is primitive type.You have to use '==' to compare primitives.
You can only invoke the compareTo() or equals() methods on Integer object.

First problem is you are reading the input file line by line and putting each line as an entry to array.Then you are trying to compare the entered word against an entire line in file.If you are trying to do word search, try splitting the input file contents to words.

Another mistake is using == to compare string.You mustn't use == to compare Strings.Use equals() method instead.

Comment: Initially, I had == in place of .compareTo(). However, It was giving me the output I gave in the OP, despite the word being in my .txt file.